# Redirect to page on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am trying to redirect to the previous page on button click but things are not going so well here is my code:

```
private string previousPage = string.Empty;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( Request.UrlReferrer != null)
    {
        previousPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
        CrossSideScriptingErrorCheck.Text = previousPage;
    }  
}
protected void BackButton_Click( object sender , EventArgs e )
{      
   Response.Redirect(previousPage);
}
```

When I first get directed to this page the previousPage variable stores the correct URL but after I click on the button for some reason previousPage value is change to the curent page url and i get sent back to the curent page.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I corect it?

**EDIT**

I wrapped the code like this:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
   {
       if( Request.UrlReferrer != null ) {
           previousPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
           CrossSideScriptingErrorCheck.Text = previousPage;
       }   
   }
```

And I get redirected to a page that I did not create and has a link.On the page is written:

```
Object moved to here.
```

"here" is a link and when I cliked it I get sent back to the page I pressed the button

Comment: try put that in if(!IsPostBack()){}

Comment: It is a bit more complicated.  You have to keep track of the valid referrers (see my answer below).

Comment: I just saw the edit.  Please try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a postback, the referrer is the page itself, so this is expected behaviour :-)

One solution would be to have something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack) Session["prev"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    if(Session["prev"] == null) {some code that disables the back button goes here!}
}
protected void BackButton_Click( object sender , EventArgs e )
{      
   Response.Redirect(Session["prev"] as string);
}
```

The reason why this answer works and the others posted so far do not, is that I am using Session["prev"] to remember the most recent valid referrer.  So the trick is to 1) realise that when you have a postback the referer is url of the page itself (which the OP did) and 2) remember the last non-post referrer URL so that you can use it when the Back button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test for a postback. When you click the button the page is posted back to the server and the referrer becomes the page you are on and the value you want is overwritten.

```
 private string previousPage = string.Empty;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if( Request.UrlReferrer != null)
        {
            previousPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
            CrossSideScriptingErrorCheck.Text = previousPage;
        }
    }  
}
protected void BackButton_Click( object sender , EventArgs e )
{      
   Response.Redirect(previousPage);
}
```

Comment: @skyfoot - agreed. Besides, there is nothing wrong with Page.IsPostBack - they both work.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot put it in `IsPostBack` that y its working like this

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   if( Request.UrlReferrer != null)
    {
        previousPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
        CrossSideScriptingErrorCheck.Text = previousPage;
    }
}
```

code like this to work with it...

Answer (score 0):

When you click on your button, the page load is executed before the click event, so it is resetting the value of your previousPage variable.  You need to wrap it in a check to make sure it's not been posted back, like so:

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    previousPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am the last to answer but was first to comment

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(!IsPostBack)
 {   
  if( Request.UrlReferrer != null)
    {
        previousPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
        CrossSideScriptingErrorCheck.Text = previousPage;
    }  
  }
}
```